# Avoid automatic cursor hide

Tags: mouse, cursor, scrolling, mouse-pointer, unclutter

My cursor hides after a few seconds of not moving it. The problem is it also disables the scroll option, so it's very annoying when reading texts etc.

Initially I thought it could be a consequence of having installed `unclutter` to help me solve a completely-disappeared-cursor problem. But I removed unclutter and it continues to happen all the same.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: After removing `unlcutter`it only happens with google chrome. The other programs I checked are fine (gedit, the file system, terminal, matlab, document viewer, word...). In any case, I imagine taking off the hide-cursor thing would solve it all.